# modifying int and float in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

so i have a simple task, take a user input that in either Fahrenheit or Celsius and convert it to the opposite of what he inputs.
for example user enters 50F i return 10C.
this is what i made and it works:

```
temp_to_convert = input("Insert the temperature you would like to convert: ").upper()
if temp_to_convert.endswith("F"):
    converted_temp = temp_to_convert.replace("F","")
    converted_temp = (float(converted_temp) * 5 - 160)/9
    print( str(converted_temp) + "C")

elif temp_to_convert.endswith("C"):
    converted_temp = temp_to_convert.replace("C","")
    converted_temp = (float(converted_temp) * 9 + 160)/5
    print(str(converted_temp) + "F")
```

but problem is i dont know how to get rid of the decimal point when the user inputs a whole number
for example user inputs 50F its returning 10.0C and not just 10C . tried searching around found a method called  `is_integer()` but i cant make it work ... help? thanks.

Comment: Check if the round function resolve your question...
round(converted_temp)
print( str(round(converted_temp)) + "C")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an if statement to both conversions:

```
#temp_to_convert = input("Insert the temperature you would like to convert: ").upper()
#if temp_to_convert.endswith("F"):
    #converted_temp = temp_to_convert.replace("F","")
    #converted_temp = (float(converted_temp) * 5 - 160)/9

    if converted_temp == round(converted_temp): # If converted_temp = round(converted_temp), that means converted_temp is an integer
        print(str(round(converted_temp)) + "C")
    else:
        print(str(converted_temp) + "F")

#elif temp_to_convert.endswith("C"):
    #converted_temp = temp_to_convert.replace("C","")
    #converted_temp = (float(converted_temp) * 9 + 160)/5

    if converted_temp == round(converted_temp): # If converted_temp = round(converted_temp), that means converted_temp is an integer
        print(str(round(converted_temp)) + "F")
    else:
        print(str(converted_temp) + "F")
```

Answer (score 2):

In both print statements, first change converted_temp to int, then to string:

```
print(str(int(converted_temp)) + "C")
```

If you convert to int before calculation, you may see a different answer due to less precision. It will be better to calculate using the float value and then change the final answer to an integer.

Comment: thanks but if user inputs 50.5C i want to get the right answer which is 122.9F and not 122F . i want to get rid of that decimal point only when the result is a whole number .

Comment: @roishamayev That's what I said to one of the answers.

Comment: @AnnZen i saw now , thanks again

Comment: @roishamayev and AnnZen now I see what you mean

Answer (score 1):

change this part

```
converted_temp = (float(converted_temp) * 5 - 160)/9
```

to

```
converted_temp = int((float(converted_temp) * 5 - 160)/9)
```

the float function that keeps you having the 10.0
int function will remove that .0

**note: if you care about rounding,, check round function

Comment: revised it, wasnt aware about the brackets

Comment: The OP wanted to convert numbers like 10.0 to 10, said nothing about converting numbers like 7.3 to 7.

Comment: he's lucky he got 10.0 as the answer, he might need to think what he should do when the answer is 7.3 or 7.9. will he keep it as 7? or round it down/up? but yeah, for now, he just want 10.0 to 10. maybe Im overthinking it

Comment: If the OP knows about float, why wouldn't the OP know about int :)